# How to pass in empty/zero value to controller for establishing key

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working to try have a "smart" controller method that can detect if the user is sending a new question or updating an existing one in the database. The problem I have is I can't seem to tell the ModelState.IsValid method "this QuestionID is empty, so treat it as new" or else "update the record". When the value is 0 for QuestionID, I don't get a ModelState.IsValid == true, resulting in nothing posting to the database. The key seems to lie in the QuestionID property, but I seem to be missing something obvious. Can anyone help me out?

Flow: jQuery passes data to the controller via AJAX and the controller returns a response.

**jQuery Code**

```
function questionField() {
            var TopicID = $("#TopicID").val();
            var QuizID = $("#QuizID").val();
            var QuestionID = $("#QuestionID").val();
            var Question = $("#quizQuestion").val();
            var token = $("#quizQuestionsForm > [name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();
            $("#questionSaveArea").effect("slide", "fast");


            //Start building update string
            var questionData = "__RequestVerificationToken=" + token;

            //Wrote this "backward" because QuestionID != undefined will not work based on how 
            //JS handles objects. The variable already exists, but a backwards check will allow this to pass correctly.
            if (undefined != QuestionID)
            {
                questionData += "&QuestionID=" + QuestionID;
            }
            else
            {
                question += "&QuestionID=";
            }


            //MUFFIN: Add an active question parameter

            questionData += "&Question=" + Question + "&QuizID=" + QuizID + "&TopicID=" + TopicID;


            //Don't accept blanks
            if (Question != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../../QuizQuestions/PostQuestionData",
                    data: questionData,
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",


                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data != "Fail")
                        {
                            console.log("Question saved! Question ID is: " + data);

                            $("#QuestionID").val(data);

                            //QuestionID now exists, get existing Answers (sub function enables fields)
                            getPreviousAnswers();


                            //Enable the addAnswer button();
                            addAnswer();

                            $("#questionSaveArea")
                                        .delay('500')
                                        .fadeIn('fast')
                                        .html("<small><em>saved</em></small>");
                        }

                        if (data == "Fail")
                        {
                            alert("Cannot save question! Please try again, or contact support.");
                            $("#questionSaveArea")
                                        .delay('500')
                                        .fadeIn('fast')
                                        .html("<small><em>error</em></small>");
                        }

                    },

                    error: function () {
                        $("#questionSaveArea")
                                    .delay('500')
                                    .fadeIn('fast')
                                    .html("<small><em>unable to save, please try again</em></small>");
                    }
                }); //end AJAX


            }

            if (Question === "") {
                $("#questionSaveArea")
                                .delay('500')
                                .fadeIn('fast')
                                .html("<small><em>cannot save, empty question</em></small>");
            };


        }
```

**Controller Code**

```
// POST: QuizQuestions/PostQuestionData
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostQuestionData([Bind(Include = "QuestionID,Question,TopicID,isValidQuestion,QuizID")] QuizQuestions quizQuestions)
        {
            //If statement to catch new questions
            //Questions will be active by default for new questions
            if(quizQuestions.QuestionID == 0)
            {
                quizQuestions.IsValidQuestion = true;

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    db.QuizQuestions.Add(quizQuestions);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return Content(quizQuestions.QuestionID.ToString());
                };

                //The model state is not valid here so a fail flag is sent
                return Content("Fail");

            }

            else
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        db.Entry(quizQuestions).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                        return Content("Success"); 
                    }

                    catch
                    {
                        return Content("No change was detected. Skipping save.");
                    }

                };
                return Content("Fail");

            };
        }
```

**Model**

```
[Table("QuizQuestions")]
    public class QuizQuestions
    {

        [Column("QuestionID")]
        [Key]
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }

        [Column("IsValidQuestion")]
        [Display(Name = "question active?")]
        public virtual bool IsValidQuestion { get; set; }


        [Column("Question")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="question is required to proceed")]
        [Display(Name = "question")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Question { get; set; }

        [Column("TopicID")]
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int TopicID { get; set; }

        [Column("QuizID")]
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int QuizID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<QuizAnswers> QuizAnswers { get; set;} 

    }
```

Comment: in your javascript you are passing nothing to quesitonid but in controller your are checking for 0..perhaps you need question += "&QuestionID=0";

Comment: Have you checked the ModelState.Values for Errors to find exactly what the error is that is making the ModelState.IsValid to return false?

Comment: @EricKing It's saying the QuestionID field is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a couple options:

option 1: Change QuestionID to be nullable int ? in the model, then test for null in the controller action to create a new question.

option 2: In the JS code calling your controller action set QuestionID to some testable value like QuestionID=-1, then test -1 in the controller to create a new question.

@Zaki - Is correct, make sure you are setting questionData correclty with QuestionID=0 in JS before calling the controller.